# R - Creating multiple objects and assign them different values

Tags: r, object

im new to the programming world, but I would like to know how I can assign different values to objects I generated. I want to assign the objects 1:28 the value "index" after i ran this script. I change the filename and rerun the script, so different "index" values are generated and i want to stores these values in a txt file.

```
    wave<-readWave("myfile.wav")
    waveenv<-env(wave, f=48000, envt="hil", plot=FALSE)
    thvalue<-th(waveenv)
    wavespec<-meanspec(wave, f=48000, wl=1024, wn="hanning", plot=FALSE)
    shvalue<-sh(wavespec)
    index<-thvalue*shvalue   
    for(i in 1:28)
    assign(paste('obj',i,sep=''),NULL)
```

part I need help with :)

```
    ##obj1:28<-index
    ##list<-c(obj1:28)
    ##lapply(list, write, "test.txt", append=TRUE)
```

Thanks for the help. I dont want to recreate the index value 28 times and I know, that obj1:28 has no meaning :) I run the script, get an index value, want to store this value in an object (e.g. obj1). Then I rerun the script and want to store the new index-value in obj2...so in the end i can lapply a txt file and save all obj-values to a txt file. But I'm an idiot :) I just append the index value I get. Total blockhead :/

Comment: Why not skip the `assign` stage and just write directly to file?

Comment: `obj1:28` has no meaning. I'm guessing you wanted something like `for (jj in ls(pattern='obj')) assign(jj,index) ` .  But in any case why are you trying to load up 28 objects with the *same* data, i.e. `index` ?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest this instead:

```
wave<-readWave("myfile.wav")
waveenv<-env(wave, f=48000, envt="hil", plot=FALSE)
wavespec<-meanspec(wave, f=48000, wl=1024, wn="hanning", plot=FALSE)
index<-th(waveenv)*sh(wavespec)

lapply(1:28, function(.)write(x=index, file="test.txt", append=TRUE))
```

This will simply replicate the value `index` 28 times. Is this what you want?

Note: I've simlified your code a little bit :-)